Unable to fetch JSON ARRAY elements by using jsonpath/ xpath in WSO2 EI / MI
I have sample JSON Payload shared below.
{
              "multisetAttribute": [
                {
                  "attributes": [
                    {
                      "name": "Loading/Discount Type",
                      "value": "Bonus Discount"
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "Premium of Cover",
                      "value": "9550"
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "LD Rate",
                      "value": "0.35"
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "LD Amount",
                      "value": "3343"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "attributes": [
                    {
                      "name": "Loading/Discount Type",
                      "value": "Renewal Loading - OD"
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "Premium of Cover",
                      "value": "1862"
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "LD Rate",
                      "value": "0.0"
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "LD Amount",
                      "value": "0"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "attributes": [
                    {
                      "name": "Loading/Discount Type",
                      "value": "Experience Based Discount"
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "Premium of Cover",
                      "value": "6208"
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "LD Rate",
                      "value": "0.7"
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "LD Amount",
                      "value": "4345"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "name": "Loading Discount Details",
              "value": null
            }

From above payload, I am trying to fetch "LD Rate" value which resides inside inner JSON Array named as "attributes".
Since we have multiple "attributes" inner JSON Array , to fetch "LD Rate" element there is one specific condition ie In which compartment "Loading/Discount Type" value comes as "Experience Based Discount", from that compartment,  I should fetch "LD Rate" value (in this case 0.7)
Note: we should not pass array position to fetch element , Because this is dynamic one, we may receive more "attributes" json array.
Below xpath I tried.
<property expression="//multisetAttribute[*]/attributes[*]/name[text()='Loading/Discount Type']/../value[text()='Experience Based Discount']/text()" name="LD_Rate" scope="default" type="STRING"/>

Till this point as per above expression it is printing like "Experience Based Discount" as LD_Rate. really not sure how to navigate to next element value (ie LD Rate) in same node.
Tried below xpath expression which is not giving "LD Rate" value.
<property expression="//multisetAttribute[*]/attributes[*]/name[text()='Loading/Discount Type']/../value[text()='Experience Based Discount']/../name[text()='LD Rate']/../value/text()" name="LD_Rate" scope="default" type="STRING"/>

Sample API Code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/jsonarrayapi" name="jsonarrayapi"
    xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST">
        <inSequence>
            <property expression="//multisetAttribute[*]/attributes[*]/name[text()='Loading/Discount Type']/../value[text()='Experience Based Discount']/../name[text()='LD Rate']/../value/text()" name="LD_Rate" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <log level="custom">
                <property expression="//multisetAttribute[*]/attributes[*]/name[text()='Loading/Discount Type']/../value[text()='Experience Based Discount']/../name[text()='LD Rate']/../value/text()" name="LD_Rate" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            </log>
            <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                <format>"LD_Rate":"$1"}</format>
                <args>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:LD_Rate"/>
                </args>
            </payloadFactory>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>

Can someone help us to find out XPATH or JSON path expression for this issue?

This should get you all of the values.
Direct approach:
$.multisetAttribute.*.attributes[?@.name == 'LD Rate'].value

Recursive search:
$..[?@.name == 'LD Rate'].value

The direct approach will get only the nodes at that specific location in the tree.
The recursive approach will get you all of the LD Rate nodes, regardless of where they appear in the hierarchy.

Hi @gregsdennis
Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately above shared  json path expression not working as expected. Checked via https://jsonpath.com/. As I mentioned in the question, to fetch "LD Rate" element there is one specific condition ie In which compartment "Loading/Discount Type" value comes as "Experience Based Discount", from that compartment, I should fetch "LD Rate" value (in this case 0.7)

Yes, sorry.  Was responding from mobile, and I misread the structure.  I've updated and tested at https://json-everything.net/json-path (my processor).  It should work at jsonpath.com also.

Hi @gregsdennis
Thanks again for your effort, still above corrected expression not giving expected results in https://jsonpath.com/ site. if you don't mind, kindly check expression once again in the same site. PS: please check that specific condition as well . condition: In which compartment "Loading/Discount Type" value comes as "Experience Based Discount", from that compartment, I should fetch "LD Rate" value (in this case 0.7)
